# Scikit Learn Pipeline: Calling .fit() and .score() vs cross_val_score()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

Imagine we have the following pipeline:

```
example_pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('selector', SelectKBest(k=len(X.columns)-5)),
    ('classifier', KNeighborsClassifier())
])
```

Now we want to get the performance of the pipeline with:

```
# 1)
cross_val_score(example_pipe, X, y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy').mean()

# 2)
example_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
example_pipe.score(X_test, y_test)
```

How is the first different from the second in regards to the score we get (except of course that it does cross-validation)? Do we have to call `example_pipe.fit()` before using `cross_val_score()`.

I've found the following methods in the documentation, but it's a bit confusing because I thought that calling `.fit()` already implies calling `.transform()`.

> fit(X[, y]) --> Fit the model
>
> fit_predict(X[, y]) --> Applies fit_predict of last step in pipeline
> after transforms.
>
> fit_transform(X[, y]) --> Fit the model and transform with the final
> estimator
>
> score(X[, y, sample_weight]) --> Apply transforms, and score with the
> final estimator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do we have to call example_pipe.fit() before using cross_val_score()?

If you go to [Scikit-Learn Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html), you find the answer:

[image]

`cross_val_score` first fits your `example_pipe`, then gets the score of the cross validation.